# How to add score from yes and no answers?

Tags: python

I want to tally up a score using Yes and No answers and I can't seem to be able to figure that out. I know it's going to be super simple when I see it, but for some reason, I can not.

```
duckPerc = 0
Yes = 'Yes'
No = 'No'

def duckPerc():
    for i in duckPerc:
        if True:
            duckPerc +=1
        else:
            duckPerc += 0

q1 = input('Do you have feathers(Yes or No)?: ')
if Yes:
    Yes == True
else:
    No == False
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this

```
scoreYes= 0
scoreNo= 0
while True:
    q1 = input('Do you have feathers(Yes or No)?: ')
    if q1.lower() in ["yes", "y"]:
        scoreYes+= 1
    elif q1.lower() in ["no", "n"]:
        scoreNo+= 1
    elif q1 == "stop":
        break
    else:
        print("invalid input")
print(scoreYes)
print(scoreNo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert string statements for the program to check. Right now your program is checking for variable that does not exist currently in the program. You also need to assign a parameter for the program to check the input against.

To fix this you need to rewrtie the if,else statements.

```
if q1 == 'Yes':
    Yes == True
elif q1 == 'No':
    No == False
else:
    print("That doesn't make sense")
```

the else statement is unecessary, but this is the simplest way to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need function, only what you need is to add 1 when input is yes

```
duckPerc = 0
Yes = 'Yes'
No = 'No'

q1 = input('Do you have feathers(Yes or No)?: ')
if q1 == Yes:
    duckPerc += 1
```

Another using seprate y/n scores:

```
Yes = 0
No = 0
while True:
    q1 = input('Do you have feathers(Yes or No)?: ')
    if q1.lower() in ["yes", "ye", "y"]:
        Yes += 1
    elif q1.lower() in ["no", "nope", "n", "nop"]:
        No += 1
```